# How to commit a folder to gitHub

Tags: github, commit

I am new to GitHub, able to create a README textfile and commit that (from my local machine to github site) but now my problem is, i have one folder and i need to commit that folder to git hub, can any one of you help m e on this.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you tried `git add dir`? Note, that there's no way to commit empty directory to git.

Comment: little trick: Install SmartGit. It will make your life easier

Comment: @KL - 7:Created one Repository and to that Repository i am commit one text file from my local machine and now my problem is i want to add one folder to that Repository and i don't have any idea about that

Answer (score 18):

Try this :

```
git add myfolder
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple. Follow some steps-

1. Just click on the **Upload files** button.
2. Now you can see a window where you can drag or upload the files.
3. Just drag your required folder and it will upload in the repository (don't click on the **choose your files** button, it will upload your files only, not folder. )

Answer (score 1):

`git add FOLDERNAME`

After that, you can do a normal commit + push as you did it with the README file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
git commit folder_path -m "your comment"
```

folder_path should full path, something like this `../../../folder_path`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to update your folder to GitHub:

Step 1: Navigate to your local repository(folder) that contains your code and initialize it

```
$ cd folderName (or) $ cd ~/FolderName 
$git init
```

Step 2: Add the folder to be a part of trackable files/folders list in GitRepository

```
$ git add FolderName/
```

step 3: Commit the folder(save your changes made) to GitRepository

```
$ git commit -m "Some Message"
```

step 4 : connect GitHub to your local machine, Here you add a remote name origin to GitHub Repository. You can get this URL from "Clone or Download" link from your GitHub

```
$ git remote add origin URL
```

Step 5: Push the committed files/folders to HitHub repository

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

Refresh the GitHub repository and you could save the folder committed to respository.
I hope this would be helpful!!